# Word template for dynamics Crm 2016

Tags: dynamics-crm, word-template

I have to show data on my word template from other entities linked to my main entity. but the standard template doesn't provide this possibility whene the depth of the association is more than 1.

I tried to unzip the template and add the noeud into the item1.xml file to get more level on the mapping xml tree but it doesn't work.

I will be thankhful if some one can suggest some paths to follow.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First of all you need to check all relationship in your work template. Go to Settings-Templates-New-Word-Choose Entity and press Select Entity, here you can see all fields and entity relationships that will be available in Word Template. Then you need to enable Developer Tab in your Ms Office Word. You can read about this here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm-customer-center/using-word-templates-in-dynamics-365.aspx

Comment: OP is asking about how to include more entities than what's available by default in word templates